# VBA excel nesting data from excel into a table in word (copying excel data into Word table)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to paste a table into word from excel with VBA Excel.

I'm pasting it into a cell in a single column table of 4 rows I created in Word. So it is essentially a nested table.

I keep getting,

> Run-time error 4605: Method 'PasteAsNestedTable' of object Selection failed

I'm trying to use PastAsNestedTable because otherwise I get the Run-time error about cells not matching as it is trying to merge the two tables.

So I get it is saying `PasteAsNestedTable` isn't a method of selection but how do I get around this issue?

My updated code goes:

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc as Word.Document
Dim tabl1 as Table, tabl2 as Table
Set wdApp = new Word.Application
With wdApp
     .visible = True
     .Activate
     .Document.Add(location)

Set wdDoc=wdApp.ActiveDocument
With wdApp
   Charts("chart1").ChartArea.Copy
     .Selection.GoTo what:=-1,Name:="chart1"
     .selection.Paste
(Then add some more charts)

End With 

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F10").Copy
    Set wdDoc=wdApp.ActiveDocument
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("table").Range.PasteAsNestedTable

With wdApp
(Then repeat above pasting charts + tables)
```

`

If I made the Range a `ListObjects` could I somehow copy it in that way?

Comment: Have you read this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837670.aspx

Comment: You code can't work since `wdApp` is a new Word Application with a totally empty document. There cannot be a Bookmark "tableplace". And `.Selection.GoTo what:=-1 Name:="tableplace"` lacks a comma between the parameters. So it will not compile.

Comment: @AxelRichter,  I've left out a line where I open a template. The template has a bookmark named "tablespace". I've used the `.Selection.GoTo what:=-1 Name:="tableplace"` format for copying charts to other bookmarks in the word doc and that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Selection.
This here works for me (Word with correct document already opened):

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Sheets(1).Range("A1:F10").Copy
Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
wdDoc.Bookmarks("tableplace").Range.PasteAsNestedTable
```

You can of course replace `GetObject(, "Word.Application")` with your `new Word.Application` and set wdDoc as `wdApp.Documents.Open(pathtoyourdoc)`.
Then combine with my answer from your other thread, replace `wd`there with `wdDoc` and you should be good to go.

**Edit** I have changed my code to reflect your current variables and bookmark names:

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim tabl1 As Table, tabl2 As Table

Set wdApp = New Word.Application

With wdApp
     .Visible = True
     .Activate
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Location)
End With

Charts("chart1").ChartArea.Copy
wdDoc.Bookmarks("chart1").Range.Paste

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F10").Copy
wdDoc.Bookmarks("table").Range.PasteAsNestedTable

'(Continue like this for other charts + tables)
```

Note:

- Do not use Doument**s**.Add, as this will add a new ***empty*** document based on a template. This will not have your bookmarks. Use `.Open` instead.
- Close `With` blocks properly
- Do not set the same object over and over again. Set it once and work with that object
- Do not use `Selection` unless absolutely necessary. Not necessary in this case.

Comment: it kind of works. I need to paste in 3 tables in three different locations. For the first two I get the Runtime error '4605': method 'pasteasnestedtable' of object 'range' failed. But when I hit debug and F5 it pastes it correctly and continues on. However for the third one it says Run-time error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist.  I have no idea hot to fix this

Comment: @JoshD Please post the exact line where the error happens. Sheet unknown? Cell range out of bounds? Bookmark name typo or deleted before insert? So many possibilities.

Comment: Ha, was just in the middle of typing. The third paste RE 5941 was my typo. Apologies. The RE 4605 occurs at the line: `wdDoc.Bookmarks("tablespace").Range.PasteAsNestedTable`

Comment: Alright. Bookmarks "tableplace", "tablespace" exist? You speak of 3 paste operations. Got 3 different bookmarks? Addressing them all properly? Let's see code.

Comment: Yeah all good, sheets are labelled correctly, as is the range and there are three different bookmarks, i.e. "tablespace2" and "tablespace3"

Comment: Code or it didn't happen! :-} Plus line of error please.

Comment: `Sheets(1).Range("A1:F10").Copy Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument wdDoc.Bookmarks("tableplace").Range.PasteAsNestedTable` . The error occurs on the final line for all three pastes saying Run-time error '4605': method'pasteasnestedtable'of object'range'failed

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect the current code situation. The error could be with any of `Sheet()`, `Range()`, or `Bookmarks()` and cannot be identified without context.

Comment: SO currently I have it set as:
`Dim wdApp As Word.Application

Comment: Ok now I get the RT error: 4605 This command is not available. When coping the first chart in. IE at the `.wdDoc. Bookmarks (......` row. I can't overide it like the old error. However if I drag the fellow arrow past the charts to the table it will past no problem.

Comment: No-brainer: a chart is not a table and can therefore not be pasted as a nested table. Paste it as something else instead: normal paste, bitmap...

Answer (score 0):

You can set DocVariables in Word.  Google this if you don't know how to do this.  Then, run the script below, from Excel.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
'On Error Resume Next

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("FirstName").Value = Range("FirstName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("LastName").Value = Range("LastName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("Another").Value = Range("Another").Value


objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

'On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```